# Rails run inbuilt method based on registration id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My app is setup as when a user is registered, a profile is created for them so I use `before_create :build_profile` with a foreign key `user_id` on the profile's model.

**User Model:**

```
...

has_one :profile
before_create :build_profile #-> inbuilt method

...
```

Now I have two registration types: reg1 and reg2. Reg2 can only have a company profile so here comes the question. Can I build a company profile based on the user registration type during registration? This is the picture:

**User Model:**

```
...

before_create :build_profile #-> inbuilt method
has_one :company
# before_create :build_company if registration_id == 2

...
```

**Registration model was created like this:**

```
Registration.create(name: 'foo', company_id: 2)
```

**A User table has the foreign key:**

```
...

:registration_id => :integer,

...
```

So when a user is created and their registration is set to 2, I want to run `:build_company`. Is this possible?

**Reason for my answer so please, correct me!!**

**My devise registration_controller.rb:**

```
def create
    super do |resource|
        if params[:registration_id]
            resource.registration_id = params[:registration_id]
            if resource.registration_id == 2
                resource.save
            elsif resource.registration_id == 1
                resource.save!
            end
        end
    end
end
```

**My registration view form has this hidden_field:**

```
<%= hidden_field_tag 'registration_id', params[:registration_id] %>
```

So please tell me why the down votes???

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Ruby [ActiveRecord::Callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) to perform what happens before or after a user is created. Sine you need the user id, that created after a user is saved to the database, you will need to use the `after_save` callback:

**User.rb:**

```
...

after_save :create_company # no need for this (updated)

has_one :profile
has_one :company
before_create :build_profile #-> inbuilt method

def create_company
  if self.registration_id == 2
    c = Company.new(user_id: self.id, registration_id: 2) #assigns the user_id to company.
    c.save
  end
end

...
```

Upon restarting my server I now saw the errors. Weird how it works great until restart. Any how, I've seen what you all were saying and sorry for being so naive. I removed the method from `user.rb` and changed up the `registration_controller.rb`:

```
def create
    super do |resource|
        if params[:registration_id]
            resource.registration_id = params[:registration_id]
            if resource.registration_id == 2
                resource.save!(Company.create(user_id: User.last.id, registration_id: 2))
            elsif resource.registration_id == 1
                resource.save!
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: The difference with my solution is that it calls the `create_company` if the condition is met.

Comment: That's true but my approach is that I can assign more fields: `Company.new(a: 1, b: 2)`

Comment: Same with my approach. Again this doesn't change the nature of what is happening in the `create_company` method...

Comment: This wont work as `self.id` is null. You have to use `after_commit` instead.

Comment: @Oleander I am sticking to my answer. `self.id`, works and it is not null. Im assigning the model id to user_id.

Comment: @Sylar `self.id` will always be null when creating a new object using `User.create`. Try it for your self using `puts self.id` in `create_company`.

Comment: @Oleander that's way I use `after_save`. When a user is saved to the db, an id is created. Correct? I then use that id for the company user_id. I can create a new user, using rails_admin and it creates a company profile based on the registration id. This works.

Comment: @Sylar This will fail for example: `User.create(registration_id: 2)`. It will result in `Company#user_id` being null.

Comment: @Sylar Do you understand the reason `self.id` is null in the first place? I'm getting the feeling that you don't.

Comment: Here is another failure. `user = User.create(registration_id: 2); 5.times { user.save }; Company.count # => 5 `

Comment: @Oleander bro, my app is working. There is no error. I can create a new user: email and password. I then press "register". Boom. User is created and a company profile (assuming the params reg id is 2). That company profile has a user_id of the User id.

Comment: I don't mind if you use this code by your self and don't tell anyone, but you've posted this as solution in a public forum. What happens when users copies this, spend 5h debugging to realise that the code they thought was valid introduced an array of bugs. And I get it. You've found a way around the bugs I just pointed out, but that doesn't mean that you or someone else wont be effected by them. Do things the right way instead of hacks like this.